# How to get the "first sheet" in Python Google Sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using the Python googleapiclient to get the contents of a Sheet. The API currently requires specifying the sheet name. That's fine, but sometimes the name of my sheet changes, and then I get an exception `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/...` because the hardcoded sheet name could no longer be found. I want to make it work for all cases.

I couldn't find anything like wildcards, so how can I just get the default/first sheet found in the spreadsheet?

Existing Code:

```
sheets_service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
content = sheets_service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range='Sheet1').execute()
```

What I want:

```
sheets_service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
content = sheets_service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range='*').execute()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, in order to retrieve the sheet name of the 1st tab, how about using "Method: spreadsheets.get" of Sheets API? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, "Method: spreadsheets.get" is used.

```py
sheets_service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# Here, the sheet name of the 1st tab is retrieved.
res = sheets_service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id).execute()
sheetName = res.get("sheets", [])[0].get("properties").get("title")

content = sheets_service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=sheetName).execute()
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, "Method: spreadsheets.get" is not used.

```py
sheets_service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
content = sheets_service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range="A:ZZZ").execute()
```

- In this modification, only a1Notation of the range without including the sheet name is used. In this case, the values of the 1st tab are retrieved. In the current stage, the maximum column is `ZZZ`. So, as a sample, "A:ZZZ" is used. But, if you have already known the range, you can use the specific range. When the sheet name is not included, the values are always retrieved from the 1st tab.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: I tested your answer (strategy 1) and it is almost correct, but there is one modification required. The value returned (`content`) gives other metadata of the API response which causes a problem when trying to get the sheet contents. You have to add `content['values']` after the last line and it will give the expected result. Thanks.

Comment: @starmandeluxe Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

### You can get the name of the first sheet with [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Thereby, you can use the knowledge that the first sheet of a spreadsheet always has the `sheetId` `0`.

- Specify the `fields` you are interested in when making the request:

`sheets = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, fields='sheets(properties(sheetId,title))'`

- This will return you an object containig the sheetIds and titles of all sheets within the spreadsheet:

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "sheetId": 0,
        "title": "Sheet1"
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "sheetId": 457388739,
        "title": "Sheet2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- Now you only need to filter this object to retrieve the title that belongs to the `sheetId` `0`.
- This title you can use then instead of `Sheet1` to specify the range in `spreadsheets.values.get`